# System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\RDS\RDS.txt' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, forms

after running my application, i have this error message minutes later. why? i will be appreciated if you help me with your answers.

here is the source code of my Form1: https://github.com/betimen/txtRDS/blob/master/Form1.cs

(ERROR MESSAGE)

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\RDS\RDS.txt' because it is being used by another process.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path)
at WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1.timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.5.27.0 built by: FX453PREVIEWREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
txtRDS
Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/hevi%20sms/Downloads/txtRDS.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.5.27.0 built by: FX453PREVIEWREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.5.27.0 built by: FX453PREVIEWREL
 CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.5.27.0 built by: FX453PREVIEWREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.5.27.0 built by: FX453PREVIEWREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.5.27.0 built by: FX453PREVIEWREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.5.27.0 built by: FX453PREVIEWREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.
For example:
<configuration>
<system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>
When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: have u check my answer? is it help for you ?

Comment: yes i read your answer and i was busy with work i couldnt reply to you now i have free time and i am replying to your answer 1 sec

Comment: i can't read the answer of @SachithMW at the moment. any opinions?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the text file opened in another application? Sounds like there's a program that has the text file opened and is preventing your program from accessing it. This could you find out which application is doing that:
http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-find-out-which-windows-process-using-file.htm

Comment: no i didn't open that text file in another application. because i know it is throwing error after some seconds when timer resets if i open that text file in notepad to check if textbox text of form1 has written and saved successfully. i tested before. the application is saving to the text file and textbox2 shows content of text file so i dont need to open in notepad. but the application should run 7/24 in the computer and should not be closed. because text file is saved with the data of textbox1.text or textbox4.text on every 10 seconds by default. but throws error after 1-2 hours.

Comment: If you're going to be writing to the same file every 10 seconds, and the file is to be only used by your single application for the entirety of its run time. It might be good to just keep the file open and not close it until the application closes. This should also resolve your issue.

Comment: i understand and yes it should be the same text file only. because there is a device that reads the content of that text file. so i need to use "close". i have checked your link and no process preventing access. i am still waiting at "resource monitor" and "process explorer" screens